# Is this LINQ statment vulnerable to SQL injection?

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

Is this LINQ statment vulnerable to SQL injection?

```
var result = from b in context.tests
    where b.id == inputTextBox.Text
    select b;
```

where context is an Entity and tests is a table.
I'm trying to learn LINQ and I thought that the benefit of it was that it wasn't vulnerable to sql injection, but some stuff I've see has said differently. Would I need to parametrize this LINQ statement to make it safer? If so, How?

Also would this be considered linq to sql or linq to entities?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Short answer: LINQ is not vulnerable to SQL injection.**

**Long answer:**

LINQ is not like SQL. There's a whole library behind the scenes that builds SQL from expression trees generated by compiler from your code, mapping the results to objects—and of course it takes care of making things safe on the way.

See [LINQ to SQL FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386929.aspx):

> Q. How is LINQ to SQL protected from
> SQL-injection attacks?
>
> A. SQL injection has been a significant risk for traditional SQL
> queries formed by concatenating user
> input. LINQ to SQL avoids such
> injection by using SqlParameter in
> queries. User input is turned into
> parameter values. This approach
> prevents malicious commands from being
> used from customer input.

Internally, it means that **when LINQ to SQL queries the database, instead of using plain values, it passes them as SQL parameters**, which means they can *never* be treated as executable code by the database. This is also true for most (if not all) ORM mappers out there.

Compare these two approaches (totally pseudo-code):

```
string name = "' ; DROP DATABASE master  --"
run ("SELECT * FROM Authors WHERE Name = '" + name + "'") // oops!

// now we'd better use parameters
SqlParameter name = new SqlParameter ("@name", "' ; DROP DATABASE master  --")
run ("SELECT * FROM Authors WHERE Name = @name", name) // this is pretty safe
```

I suggest you dive deeper into what LINQ statements actually mean and when and how they get translated to the real SQL. You may want to learn about LINQ [standard query operator translation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399342.aspx), [deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx), [different LINQ providers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_providers) et cetera. In case of LINQ, much like any abstraction technology, it is both fascinating and incredibly useful to know what's happening behind the scenes.

P.S. Everytime I see a question about SQL injection I can't help but remember this webcomic.

[image: sql injection]

Comment: However, if you are using Linq to concatenate string and input, you may still be vulnerable.

Comment: Thanks. xkcd is amazing btw. I thought that LINQ was parameterizing the queries, but I wasn't 100% sure if I was using LINQ properly/Securely

Comment: @Oded can you throw some examples where it could be vulnerable? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

No. LINQ to Entities and LINQ to SQL handle the generation of SQL Queries to avoid SQL Injection. You can use LINQPad if you're curious to see what SQL statement gets generated when you run this query with various inputs.

Whether it's LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities depends on what your `context` object is, and cannot be determined from this code snippet.

The only time you need to worry about SQL injection in LINQ is if you're using the ExecuteQuery method to run a custom SQL query ([see here](http://idunno.org/archive/2009/04/20/linq-and-sql-injection.aspx)). But at that point, you've moved away from the Language-INtegrated Query, and back into the world of generating your own strings.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ uses parameterized queries so it is not generally susceptible to SQL injection.  Your example, for instance, isn't vulnerable.

Answer (score 2):

The LINQ to Entities provider uses parametrized queries and is completely safe against SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ To SQL generates a parameterised query so it protects against SQL injection attacks

Answer (score 0):

Linq paramaterizes all queries, so isn't susceptible to SQL injection attacks. However you should still validate all of your user input as otherwise you will leave yourself open to cross site scripting attacks.

Comment: While I agree that user input should be validated, I fail to see what cross site scripting attacks have to do with it.

Comment: Well it depends on what is actually done with the data, if you display the data straight out of the database any custom scripts will/could be executed.

Comment: Oh, so you're talking about if you don't escape the HTML when you display user-entered text in the browser, right? That's not what I'd categorize as validating user input, but I see what you mean.